# How can I format this number with zero-fill and locale decimal separator?

Tags: jsp

So I thought I would do something like this in my JSP document:

```html
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Produkt</th><th>Pris</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <c:forEach var="order" items="${requestScope.orders}">
    <tr>
        <td>Carport ${order.carport.width}x${order.carport.length} cm</td>
        <td>${order.totalPrice / 100},${order.totalPrice % 100} kr.</td> <!-- yields 0.0,0 instead of 0,00 -->
    </tr>
    </c:forEach>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

`totalPrice` is a primitive `int` value, and usually in a Java context, dividing two integers (`totalPrice` and `100`) would yield an integer result. However, I found myself with a floating point in the JSP context when loading my site in the browser.

I'm looking for the following solutions:

1. Is there a way to simply cut the decimals, in JSP, when dividing two integers (i.e. rounding down, regardless of a `.9`)?
2. Is there a way to tell JSP to use commas (`,`) in place of points (`.`) when representing floating points (Danish decimals)?
3. Is there a way to zero-fill numbers in JSP (be it a floating point or an integer)?

I *could* just make two separate values in my Java code, however I wanted to see if I could resolve this in the JSP.

If one of my three questions parallel an existing one, please, do link me below. I couldn't find anything specific Googling myself. Otherwise, an answer would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `<fmt:formatNumber>`?

Comment: @DaveNewton Thank you! I'll experiment a bit with the format and get back to you. :-) And thanks for the help with the title – I didn't know how to phrase it. ;D

Comment:  No worries; mostly just detagging and removing pipes, which SO tends to discourage :)